# Building stackoverflow-like inbox in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem, public-activity

Using rails and possibly the public_activity or paper_trail gem, how could I conceptually build a user inbox: which displays latest updates that are relevant to the user.

In stackoverflow's example, there are multiple things that trigger a notification:

- When you get answers to your questions.
- When someone posts a comment on your question or answer.
- When someone posts an answer to a question you have also answered.

**Should I create a table to push notifications into and mark them as viewed when the user has seen them? Or is there is a better way to accomplish this?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Table for notifications is always good idea. You should create some rake task to clear old ones though, because it can grow very large.